# Parallax header for tableview and uiview below the header

Tags: ios, tableview, parallax

So i want to create a tableview which will be having a parallax header with an imageview inside the header and a uiview below the parallax header which will be fixed above the tableview, as if there is a uiview above the tableview.

```
--NavBar--
----Parallax header -----
----UIView------
---Tableview-cells----
```

Now the scrolling will become as this when i scroll down (for more cells).

```
--Navbar---
----UIView----
----TableviewCells scrolling---
```

Scrolling the tableview upward will decrease the header, as a parallax header should do, but the limit would be upto the uiview, after that the y of the tableview wont be decreased, and normal scrolling will commence(of course the tableview height will increase as the origin y decreases.)

Any idea how to achieve this? i got a sample code from cocoacontrols, but the desired effect comes as the tableview goes up, the uiview appears.

Here's the link to the sample code on [github](https://github.com/toandk/DTTableView)

Comment: What about [this library](https://github.com/pyro2927/ParallaxBlur) or [this one](https://github.com/quemb/QMBParallaxScrollViewController)

Comment: Havnt tried it yet, but would want the uiview below the parallax to be a standalone view, if that would be possible it would do the trick

Comment: I guess [this library](https://github.com/AugustRush/ARSegmentPageris)  is flexible library for parallax header, note the segmented control is the uiview here, and you can customize it I can guide you

Comment: Nope, static tableview content, and the logic is that the first cell would be the fixed uiview, but for dynamic content, i would have to create a static uiview by checking in `cellForRowatIndexPath` if indexpath.row == 0, too much of a problem

Comment: I am sorry but non of the libraries helped, they both are offering parallax header, but i would be needing a custom view to fit inside of them, which would be fixed